# What is the Windows "OneSettings service"?

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

Does anyone know what the "OneSettings" service is that is referred to by the following Group Polices? Among the new policies in the Windows 10 21H2 templates I found these two in the `Windows Components\Data Collection and Preview Builds` folder:

- Disable OneSettings Downloads: This policy setting controls whether Windows attempts to connect with the OneSettings service.
- Enable OneSettings Auditing: This policy setting controls whether Windows records attempts to connect with the OneSettings service to the EventLog.

Having never heard of this "OneSettings service" before, I searched online for a while but all I found was:

- Various sites mentioning these new polices but no further explanation than the policy itself provides.
- Some references to OneSettings but no real explanation on a [Required Windows diagnostic data and fields page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/required-windows-diagnostic-data-events-and-fields-2004)
- Various log file dumps, registry key listings, etc.

Comment: I've tried to determine this myself.  My only understanding is that it is a service MS "provides/requires" as of later OS builds that offers to report telemetry data back to MS about OS health, build info, etc. in order to keep the computer "healthy".  Other than diagnostic page documentation, etc. from MS as you've noted, along with sites that mention the callback URLs, I've never found definitive details about it and why it exists from Microsoft blogs or docs.

Answer (score 1):

This policy setting controls whether Windows attempts to connect with the OneSettings service to download configuration settings.
The recommended state for this setting is: Enabled.

This service offers to report telemetry data back to MS about OS health, build info, etc. in order to keep the computer "healthy"